# UPDATE VALUE IN MYSQL MARIA DB WITH JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I am trying to change the value of a column table with a sum function, this is my code:

```
For example 
c.total = (10-2-3) - (3) 
c.total = 2

update tabC c 
JOIN tabB b ON b.c_id = c.id 
set c.total = (c.v1 - c.v2 - c.v3) - IF(sum(b.payment) is not null, sum(b.payment), 0) 
where c.id= 983;
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

I think the error is sum, but how can I solve that?

Thanls in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with a subquery that uses `GROUP BY`.

```
UPDATE tabC c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment
    FROM tabB
    GROUP BY c_id) AS b ON b.c_id = c.id
SET c.total = (c.v1 - c.v2 - c.v3) - IFNULL(b.total_payment, 0)
WHERE c.id = 983
```

Answer (score 0):

You should usee a nested  subquery whit aggregated  resutl  for join

```
  update tabC c 
  JOIN  (
    select   c_id, ifnull(sum(payment),0) tot_payment
    from tabB
    group by c_id
  ) b ON b.c_id = c.id 
  set c.total = (c.v1 - c.v2 - c.v3) - b.tot_payment 
  where c.id= 983;
```